# Testing class is getting failed after converting a picklist values into global value set

Tags: global-picklist

I have a custom picklist field industry segment in opportunity object and the picklist has the value "Manufacturing" and it has access to all the record types.

I have a test class, creating opportunity by provide industry segment as "Manufacturing" it is working fine.

After that i have converted picklist values into global value set then if i am running the test class means it is getting failed saying bad value for industry segment.

Is there anything is to before converting a picklist values into global value set?

Comment: is this error occurring as a result of deploying or from within the sandbox where you made the switch to a global picklist?

Comment: in the sandbox.